# Converting 2 Right Outer Joins with a literal into LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following SQL Server query, that gets me exactly what I want:

```
SELECT        
  s.StateAbbr, 
  s.StateName, 
  s.SutaBasis, 
  s.ERRate, 
  s.HighRate, 
  p.PeoCode, 
  p.SutaReportingType, 
  p.SutaCost, 
  dc.ColorValue
FROM DefaultMapColors dc
RIGHT OUTER JOIN PEOCoverage_XRef p ON dc.CategoryName = p.SutaReportingType 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN SutaWageBasis s ON p.StateCode = s.StateAbbr AND p.PeoCode = 'VHR'
```

However, I'm having a heck of a time converting it to LINQ.  Here's what I think it ought to be:

```
var query = (from dc in DefaultMapColors
             join p in PEOCoverage_XRefs on dc.CategoryName equals p.PeoCode into p1 from p in p1.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join s in SutaWageBasis on new { p.StateCode, p.PeoCode } equals new { s.StateAbbr, "VHR" } into p2 from s in p2.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new
             {
               // snipped for brevity
             }).ToList();
```

But the error I get is "Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name, or member access.  I'm pretty sure it's the literal "VHR", but it has to be there in order to get the results I need.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Should be : new { sc = p.StateCode, pc = p.PeoCode }

Comment: That gets me past the error, but unfortunately it doesn't give me the same results as the original query.  In looking at it, it looks like it's giving me the exact opposite of what I'm looking for...  Chances are I've got the actual LINQ statement completely wrong...  Why are we using LINQ again?  SQL is just so much easier... heh heh heh

Comment: Then switch order.  The SQL code says join RIGHT on Left, but linq has LEFT on RIGHT.

Comment: I'm sorry, what?

Answer (score 0):

`p.PeoCode = 'VHR'` is not part of the joining -- it's just a where.  So, code it like one:

```
var query = (from dc in DefaultMapColors
         join p in PEOCoverage_XRefs on dc.CategoryName equals p.PeoCode into p1 
         from p in p1.DefaultIfEmpty()
         join s in SutaWageBasis on p.StateCode equals s.StateAbbr into p2
         from s in p2.DefaultIfEmpty()
         where p.PeoCode == "VHR"
         select new
         {
           // snipped for brevity
         }).ToList();
```

(I can't test that, so I don't know it the rest of it is right...)

Comment: The condition has to be in the join itself, because if I make it just the general where clause, I still do not get the results I need.

Comment: Here is a screen shot showing why the condition is part of the join, and what happens if excluded:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/fqhhlivo2ijghlq/QueryResults.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Ok then, I figured it out.

```
var query2 = (from s in SutaWageBasis
              join p in PEOCoverage_XRefs on new { sc = s.StateAbbr, pc = "VHR" } equals new { sc = p.StateCode, pc = p.PeoCode } into p1
              from p in p1.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join dc in DefaultMapColors on p.PeoCode equals dc.CategoryName into p2
              from dc in p2.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new SutaStateCoverage
              {
                  StateAbr = s.StateAbbr,
                  StateName = s.StateName,
                  SutaBasis = s.SutaBasis ?? 0.00m,
                  ERRate = s.ERRate ?? 0.00m,
                  HighRate = s.HighRate ?? 0.00m,
                  PeoCode = p.PeoCode,
                  SutaReportingType = p.SutaReportingType,
                  SutaCost = p.SutaCost,
                  ColorValue = dc.ColorValue
              }).ToList();
```

This gets me exactly what I need.

Comment: Argh... spoke too soon.... not getting any color values...  [EDIT} wrong field name, it does work when using the correct field name.  :)

Comment: That looks like you converted the `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`s into left outer joins, which is okay, but it is possible to do right outer joins in LINQ, just not straight forward :)